# GCC: accuracy of strict aliasing warnings

Tags: c, gcc, c99, strict-aliasing

I'm trying to check some of my code for strict aliasing violations, but it
looks like I've missed something while trying to understand the strict aliasing
rule.

Imagine the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long l;

    l = 0;

    *( ( unsigned short * )&l ) = 1;

    printf( "%lu\n", l );

    return 0;
}
```

Classic and basic example. With GCC 4.9 (`-Wall -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing -O3`), it actually reports the error:

```
 dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

But the following compiles fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long    l;
    unsigned short * sp;

    l       = 0;
    sp      = ( unsigned short * )&l;
    *( sp ) = 1;

    printf( "%lu\n", l );

    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding, the second example also violates the struct aliasing rule.
So why does it compile? Is it an accuracy issue in GCC, or have I missed
something with strict aliasing?

I also found the following topic: **[Why are no strict-aliasing warnings generated for this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817474/why-are-no-strict-aliasing-warnings-generated-for-this-code)**

Compiling with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` or `-Wstrict-aliasing=3` makes no difference.
But `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` does report the error on the second example.

GCC documentation says level 1 is the least accurate, and can produce a lot
of false positives, while level 3 is the most accurate...

So what's happening here? An issue with my own understanding or an issue with GCC?

**Bonus question**

I usually prefer Clang/LLVM over GCC for my projects, but it seems Clang
doesn't issue any warning about strict aliasing.
Does anyone knows why?
Is it because it is not able to detect violations, or because it does not follow
the rule when generating code?

Comment: For me, it does break it, because the compiler is allowed to assume that the value of `l` is constant in the second example.

Comment: The thing with aliasing violations is that they are difficult to detect, depending on the context it might even impossible without running the code itself. That is why it is not a constraint violation (an error that every compiler must detect) but the behavior "just" becomes undefined, simply because it would be a nightmare to write an optimizing compiler that would be able to guarantee things about this. There are very few valid reason to program with such pointer cast, and not to use an intermediate `union` or cast to `unsinged char*`.

Comment: Here -Wstrict-aliasing=1 gives the warning with "may", -Wstrict-aliasing=2 gives the warning with "will" and -Wstrict-aliasing=3 gives no warning.

Comment: @Macmade You are not missing anything, the compiler is not smart enough. The second example is the violation of semantics too, of course.

Comment: Your question is about the **sensitivity** of GCC's strict aliasing warnings, but if you already thought about it this way, you probably wouldn't ask the question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Alias analysis is generally complicated and in this case apparently the mere use of a temporary pointer between the cast and dereference was enough to throw it off. Surprisingly, GCC 4.8.2 does a better job on this code, warning at `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` as well as level 1, so this is a regression.

As for clang, it simply does not currently have the facility to warn about aliasing violations. It does absolutely take advantage of the rule in optimization. To see this in action, take this example straight from the C standard (N1570 §6.5.2.3 9))

```
struct t1 { int m; };
struct t2 { int m; };

int f(struct t1 *p1, struct t2 *p2) {
    if (p1->m < 0)
        p2->m = -p2->m;
    return p1->m;
}
```

If p1 and p2 point to the same struct, Clang (and GCC) will nevertheless return the value of `p1->m` before negation, since they may assume p2 does not alias p1 and therefore the previous negation never affects the result. [Here's the full example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aec75102e853dca1) and output with and without `-fstrict-aliasing`. For more examples, see [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) and the oft-cited [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html); strict aliasing optimizations are the final topic of the introductory post.

As for when warnings will be implemented, [the devs are quiet](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2013-July/030977.html), but they are mentioned [in clang's test suite](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/Misc/warning-flags-tree.c?view=markup&pathrev=190972), which lists `-Wstrict-aliasing=X` under the title (emphasis mine)

> These flags are *currently* unimplemented; test that we output them
>   anyway.

So it seems likely to happen at some point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the note about Clang. May I ask how do you know it?

Comment: @Macmade added a few details and references.

Comment: +1. But to clarify, perhaps change the phrase "to `return p1->m;`" to something like "to return the initial value of `p1->M`"?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Thanks, the way I had written it was actually really misleading.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing inherently wrong with

```
sp      = ( unsigned short * )&l;
```

For all the compiler knows, you might simply cast back the pointer to the correct type again.

There is also nothing inherently wrong with

```
*( sp ) = 1;
```

It's the combination of the two that's wrong.

The compiler just can't put the two together to tell you the combination is problematic (it is impossible in the general case, and not so easy in this particular case).

But

```
*( ( unsigned short * )&l ) = 1;
```

is far easier to detect, and hence the compiler does its best to do so.

Comment: Thanks, so the second example is still violating the rule, even if not detected?

Comment: @Macmade: Yes, introducing a new variable doesn't suddenly make it OK.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that at O3 the compiler decides that *because it knows variables of different types cannot alias*, `sp` is never used. Therefore it removes `sp` from the program and no error is produced.

Either that or because `l` is a known value it is being converted to a constant for use by printf. It'll still have storage because its address is taken, but that storage is never written to as far as it knows.

Comment: Thanks, and very nice guess btw. But unfortunately, I tried using `sp` and there's still no warning.

Comment: @Macmade: Then it is because l is a known value and is being converted to a constant and removed from the program.

Comment: Well, declaring it as `volatile` doesn't change anything unfortunately... But I guess @Mehrdad got it right... Thanks anyway for the answer : )

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the situation:

1. `*( ( unsigned short * )&l ) = 1;` is easier to catch, because the violation is in one line. So it's always caught.
2. With optimization, the second variation is also caught. After optimization, it's as simple as the first.
3. Without optimization, `-Wstrict-aliasing=1`, which is lazier than the default, catches it. This is because it treats the cast itself as a violation, even without the dereference (delete the dereference and see). This simplistic logic is fast, but leads to false positives.