# multidimensional array in struct c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

I've been trying this for a long time. Everything seems to work but i get a lot of warnings and just want to program it properly.
The problem is the following: I'm making a game engine. 
I provide images in 3d arrays, where the first two indices are the position and the third is the colour. So a simple 4x4 image would be:

```
static const uint8_t font_image[2][2][3] = 
{
    {{255,255,255},{255,255,255}},
    {{255,255,255},{255,255,255}}
};
```

Now every entity struct has a sprite struct. All i want is to have a reference to the 3 dimensional array in the struct.

```
struct Sprite {
    uint32_t sizeX;
    uint32_t sizeY;
    uint8_t * data;
};
```

Every image can his its own width and height, so i can't  make it

```
uint8_t [2][2][3] data;
```

I keep getting this warning:

Message 3   expected 'const uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'const uint8_t (*)[10][4][3]'    C:\Users\Elmar\Documents\GitHub\EVA-OS\EVA-OS\Libs\Game\sprite.h    28  10  EVA-OS

where this is the function to make a new sprite:

```
Sprite * sprite_new(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, const uint8_t * image)
{
    Sprite * sprite = malloc(sizeof(Sprite));
    sprite->data = image;
    sprite->sizeX = width;
    sprite->sizeY = height;
    return sprite;
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: C's multidimensional array handling sucks. I think everyone tends to just flatten everything and do the indexing logic manually, even after the introduction of VLAs.

Comment: It sounds like you really want to have `static const uint8_t font_image[SIZE_X * SIZE_Y * N]` for each image, then `data` can point to it.

Comment: I would say you have pinpointed the problem perfectly: `The problem is the following: I'm making a game engine.` - if you are making a game engine, sooner or later you will discover that is your main problem :D

Comment: what line of code is generating the error? there is no uint8_t*[10][4][3] above...

Comment: If all you want is a reference to *that* 3D array, then  `uint8_t (*data)[2][3]` will do what you want. Likewise with the parameter to your function. (And I'm having a hard time understanding precisely what "All i want is to have a reference to the 3 dimensional array in the struct." really means in this context.)

Comment: @justinmreina yeah sorry, i just picked a little sample code, no point in posting all here.

Comment: @Lawrence why would that be? i don't see the problem in there at all. It's quite difficult to find a game library written in ansi C optimized for low speed arm microcontrollers.

Comment: @user3448481 Be warned, using Mike Holt's code is broken and can fail anytime.

Comment: @self.
why and how? It was merely to get rid of the warnings. The code has been working just fine.

Comment: @user3448481 If the code is working doesn't mean it is correct. You should always follow with the types you give to the compiler. Casting to an incompatible type is wrong an bad practice. There is a perfectly reasonable solution of passing an pointer to an array along with the size information. Simply look for already existing answers to such problems( passing a multidimensional array to a function ) on this site, and adopt it to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message, it sounds like you're doing this somewhere else in your code:

```
uint8_t image[10][4][3] = { ... whatever ... };

Sprite *sprite = sprite_new(10, 4, image);
```

The problem with that is that the compiler considers the data type of `image` to be `const uint8_t (*)[10][4][3]`, not `uint8_t *`. You can make it work with a cast:

```
Sprite *sprite = sprite_new(10, 4, (uint8_t *)image);
```

As for how you declare your `Sprite` struct, user2357112 is correct. There's really no easy way to declare variable length arrays and pass them into functions in C with their size information preserved. C is kind of dumb in that regard. You always need to pass the size information as one or more separate parameters.

Comment: Casting to an incompatible type is undefined in c; you are also breaking strict aliasing. You have written a possible correct solution( passing array size), why not use it?

Comment: First off, this is not undefined behavior. Accessing a multidimensional array of `type_xyz` through a `type_xyz *` does not cause undefined behavior, provided you're using the correct array dimensions for your pointer arithmetic. Secondly, he's already passing in the size information, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting I do differently. Lastly, strict aliasing rules are there so people don't do things like casting a `struct Foo *` to a `struct Bar *`, or a `uint32_t *` to a `uint16_t *`, since those things *can* cause undefined behavior. This doesn't.

Comment: C specs say that compatible types are, and I quote: *Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.*(201x:6.2.7.1) There are additional rules to this, but none of them covers casting multidimensional pointers to single pointers. So that is already illegal.

Comment: Then we have aliasing. As per 201x:6.5.7, *An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types*, the two important lines: *a type compatible with the effective type of the object* and * a character type.*. Your cast is breaking alising.

Comment: The underlying type (`uint8_t`) is what matters here. Multidimensional arrays are laid out in memory as simple flat buffers, in a completely predictable order. Stop quoting rules and explain how **this example** is going to break. As for strict aliasing, not everything that breaks strict aliasing is something that will cause undefined behavior. One merely has to use one's brain a little and *think* about what's actually going on at the byte level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what i was looking for. No more annoying warnings. That's all what i really needed, keep forgetting to use those casts properly.

Comment: @MikeHolt Nevertheless, if the code works, it doesn't mean it is adhering to the standard. It works now, but in the future might fail. That is because you are making **an assumption** about arrays, which standard says nothing about.

Comment: @self. so what do you suggest then?

Comment: @self Oh really? Here's a quote from section 6.5.2.1 of the C11 standard, paragraph 3: "... It follows
from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest)". Read that section of the standard, then go read the Wikipedia article about [Row Major Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), and *then* come back and tell me all about how the C standard doesn't say anything about how multidimensional arrays are laid out in memory.

Comment: @MikeHolt That is irrelevant and not even an argument in this case, but still, let me respond; standard explicitly forbids casting to an incompatible type, which you are doing.

Comment: How is that irrelevant? If your only concern is whether or not you will be in compliance with your beloved standard, then yes, you got me. It's irrelevant. However, if all you want to know is whether your code is going to actually work reliably in *all* standard-compliant compilers, then it is absolutely relevant, because the standard is guaranteeing you that the memory is going to be laid out exactly how you expect it to be.

Comment: @MikeHolt Read again and again... : **standard explicitly forbids casting to an incompatible type, which you are doing.**

Comment: Yes, and despite your obvious consternation about it, the standard is also **guaranteeing** me that this code will work in every compiler on the planet that is compliant with the standard.

Comment: No, as I mentioned before, your code violates strict aliasing, and have provided necessary reference to why. Any compiler ( like -O2 gcc ) that enables that rule will break the code. This is not a theoretical concern and has been observed before.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "break" the code, because what you really mean is that if you have the strict aliasing rules turned on, it'll puke out a compiler error, which is not the same thing as the code not *working* as expected. And turning off strict aliasing is a trivial matter.

Comment: Strict aliasing detection is very hard and the compiler will usually not produce an error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214875/gcc-accuracy-of-strict-aliasing-warnings Anyone having *any* experience with it wouldn't say such nonsense.

Comment: In other words, having utterly failed to make a cogent argument as to how and why my code example is going to produce the undefined behavior you originally asserted it would, you're now trying to drag me into a broader discussion re: strict aliasing, and put me in the position to defend any and all wacky and stupid aliasing tricks. So despite the *demonstrable fact* that my code above *will* compile and run and produce the expected results on virtually any C compiler from the last 20 years, I am somehow now expected to follow you down the rabbit hole and defend a position I never put forth...

Comment: ...namely, that strict aliasing rules are stupid and should always just be turned off. Gee, no thanks. As far as my experience with strict aliasing, it sounds to me like maybe you've had *too much* experience with strict aliasing, or rather *too narrow* of an experience, and have fallen victim to the old adage "When all you've got is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail." You can't even bring yourself to admit that there might be an exception to strict aliasing rules that makes sense for practical reasons, nor to admit that the above code does not produce unexpected results.

Comment: Btw, just to save you some more typing, before you reply with yet another "but no because strict aliasing" rant, when I say my code will compile, clearly I mean with strict aliasing errors disabled, or set to warnings only (the latter of which lets you still see all the other parts of your code that might *actually* have undefined behavior).

Comment: I encourage you to learn what rant is, and also to re-read my comments in hope that you will maybe learn something. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
sprite->data = image;
```

are you allocating space for the data?

I would assume you would have to allocate space for `struct Sprite` but that will only contain space for a pointer. Then you will need to allocate space for a regoin and have data point to it. Finallly, you can `memcopy` stuff in that space ...

```
Sprite * sprite = malloc(sizeof(Sprite));
sprite -> data  = malloc( width*length*sizeof(uint8_t)   );
memcopy( ...
```

Comment: No, malloc is not possible in this case. I got very little ram space and i'm storing and loading the images right off the flash memory.
Malloc would've made everything easier though