# Why is 1.0f in C code represented as 1065353216 in the generated assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, nasm

In C I have this code block:

```
if(x==1){
    a[j][i]=1;
}
else{
    a[j][i]=0;
}
```

`a` is a matrix of float values, if I try to see the compiled assembly of this code in nasm syntax

the line `a[j][i]=0;` assignment, was coded in this way

```
dword [rsi+rdi], 0
```

but the line `a[j][i]=1;` assignment, was coded in this way

```
dword [rsi+rdi], 1065353216
```

How can **1065353216** represent a **1.0f**??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because **1065353216** is the unsigned 32-bit integer representation of the 32-bit floating point value 1.0.

More specifically, 1.0 as a 32-bit float becomes:

```
0....... ........ ........ ........ sign bit (zero is positive)
.0111111 1....... ........ ........ exponent (127, which means zero)
........ .0000000 00000000 00000000 mantissa (zero, no correction needed)
___________________________________
00111111 10000000 00000000 00000000 result
```

So the end result is 2^0 + 0, which is 1 + 0, which is 1.

You can use [binaryconvert.com](http://www.binaryconvert.com/) or [this useful converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to see other values.

As to why 127 suddenly means zero in the exponent: it's actually a pretty clever trick called [exponent bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) that makes it easier to compare floating-point values. Try out the converter with wildly different values (10, 100, 1000...) and you'll see the the exponent increases as well. Sorting is also the reason the sign bit is the first bit stored.

Answer (score 5):

The `float` is represented in [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format. The positive floats go from `0.0f` (whose bits when interpreted as integer represent 0) to `+inf` (whose bits interpreted as integer represent approximately 2000000000).

The number `1.0f` is almost exactly halfway between these two extremes. There are approximately as many positive float numbers below it (10<sup>-1</sup>, 10<sup>-2</sup>, …) as there are values above it (10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>2</sup>, …). For this reason the value of `1.0f` when its bits are interpreted as an integer is near 1000000000.

Comment: thanks. Is there a converter that I can use to avoid to become mad with all these conversion?

Comment: @AndreaF If you have the option of using Clang, it displays the float value in a comment in the generated assembly code. Otherwise, a short C program with a `union` between `uint32_t` and `float` does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the binary representation of the floating number `1.0` with the following lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main(void) {
  float a = 1.0;
  printf("in hex, this is %08x\n", *((int*)(&a)));
  printf("the int representation is %d\n", *((int*)(&a)));
  return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
in hex, this is 3f800000
the int representation is 1065353216
```

The format of a 32 bit floating point number is given by

```
1 sign bit      (s)    = 0
8 exponent bits (e)    = 7F = 127
23 mantissa bits (m)   = 0
```

You add a (implied) 1 in front of the mantissa - in the above case the mantissa is all zeros, and the implied value is

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This is 2^23 or 8388608. Now you multiply by `(-1)^sign` - which is `1` in this case.

Finally, you multiply by 2^(exponent-150). Really, you should express the mantissa as a fraction (1.0000000) and multiply by 2^(exponent-127), but that's the same thing. Either way, the result is `1.0`

That should clear it up for you.

**UPDATE** it was pointed out in the comments that my code example may invoke undefined behavior, although my `gcc` compiler generated no warnings / errors. The below code is a more correct way to prove that `1.0` is `1065353216` in `int` (for 32 bit `int` and `float`...):

```
#include <stdio.h>

union {
  int i;
  float a;
} either;

int main(void) {
  either.a = 1.0;
  printf("in hex, this is %08x\n", either.i);
  printf("the int representation is %d\n", either.i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually this code invokes UB due to aliasing violations. A modern GCC with optimizations on will likely optimize out the existence of `a` (since it's provably not accessed) and then print junk. Use `memcpy(&u, &f, 4)` where `u` has type `uint32_t` to do this safely.

Comment: Technically, `*(int*)&a` invokes undefined behavior because it breaks strict aliasing. The representation of a `float` can be inspected with a `union` (C99TC3 footnote 82 clarifies that this is legal, although of course implementation-defined) or `memcpy`.

Comment: Oddly enough, my compiler gave no warnings even with `-Wall -Wpedantic` - using gcc version 4.2.1 (mac). I appreciate your comments and agree that using a union is more correct. I will make an edit.

Comment: @Floris: I think optimization has to be on for the compiler to do the analysis necessary to detect aliasing violations. Perhaps you left it off?

Comment: @R.. I usually don't turn on optimization for little snippets of code like this. But I don't understand why you say it is "provably not accessed" in my original code. I access (and print) the contents of the address of `a` - how is that not accessing? I must be missing something obvious. And even when compiling the original with `-O3 -Wall`, I still get no warnings (and the right result). Still - I agree it is better to use a union and show that as the preferred method (leaving the other code there so people can following this discussion).

Comment: @Floris: It's provably not accessed because no expression of type `float` or with character type appeared during the lifetime of `f`, and expressions of other types cannot access the object.

Comment: @Floris Try `gcc -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing -Wall` to obtain a warning that looks like “dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules”. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214875/gcc-accuracy-of-strict-aliasing-warnings for information. I have obtained the warning on your initial code with GCC 2.8.1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq  thanks for the info and links it appears there is a blind spot in my knowledge of C - I will try to fill it. The link you gave is a good start.