# Does pointer casting really break strict aliasing?

Tags: c++, c

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>              

int main(void)
{ 
    int n = 74;
    int * pn = &n;

    short * sp;

    //sp = (short *)&n; // <-- bad
    sp = (short *)pn;   // <-- fine

    *sp = 4;
    printf("%d\n", *sp);

    return 0;
}
```

does the strict aliasing rule get broken? As far as I understand, it does, since a pointer to a short points to an int. But the compiler does not complain even if compiled with (assuming the code is in test.c)

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -Wall -std=c99 -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -O3
```

However, it does complain if the line marked as bad is uncommented, and the one marked as fine is commented.

Can someone please explain does this case really break the rule? If so, why is it not detected by the compiler? If not, why not, since according to the standard it should?

Comment: Compiler warnings don't catch everything, even things that seem obvious.

Comment: "the compiler does not complain" - welcome to C, coding without a net.

Comment: Pick one language. C and C++ have slightly different rules here.

Comment: BTW the compiler doesn't _have_ to give a diagnostic for strict aliasing violations. Compilers don't do that for most kinds of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the casting per se that violates strict-aliasing, it is the subsequent invalid lvalue access (memory reinterpretation) that violates it.

Strict-aliasing violations are really run-time violations: they are defined through *dynamic* type of the objects accessed as lvalues. For this reason, it is not always possible to catch strict-aliasing violations at compile time.

Consider the following code snippet

```
short n = 0;
int *pn = (int *) &n;     // 1
short *sp = (short *) pn; // 2
*sp = 4;
```

This code does not violate strict-aliasing rules even though it contains the same cast (2) as your original code. Even though pointer `pn` is declared as `int *`, at run time it actually points to an object of type `short`. So, the cast to `short *` and subsequent assignment to the pointee is perfectly valid. (Assuming the pointer value survives this round-trip cast.)

In cases like this the compiler apparently strives to catch the very first cast in the chain of casts: the one that that appears to be a rather obvious precursor to a potential strict-aliasing violation - cast 1 in my example. Cast 2 has fairly high potential to produce a false positive (as in my example) and the compiler does not warn about it.

Comment: `compiler strives to catch the very first cast in the chain of casts that appear to be a potential strict-aliasing violation.`  I was at looking the documentation to support this claim. Could you include a link please?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for the compiler to catch the violation at compile time unless you assign a new value by dereferencing into a different type as shown below.  If you change your code as shown below you will get the warning you were expecting.

```
int main(void)
{ 
    int n = 74; 
    //int * pn = &n;

    //short * sp;

    //sp = (short *)&n; // <-- bad
    //sp = (short *)pn;   // <-- fine

    *((short*)&n) = 4;
    printf("%d\n", n); 

    return 0;
}
```

This question shows the exact same problem and provides even more details.  [GCC: accuracy of strict aliasing warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214875/gcc-accuracy-of-strict-aliasing-warnings)

The other answer by AnT began with this statement:
"It is not the casting per se that violates strict-aliasing, it is the subsequent invalid lvalue access (memory reinterpretation) that violates it."  ....  That is correct.  My example attempts an lvalue access that violates the rule so you get the warning.